# Подскажите как обратиться ко вторичным ключам при добавлении данных в бд?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, foreign-key

Подскажите как обратиться ко вторичным ключам при добавлении данных в бд? 
При добавлении поля с названием вторичного ключа, например:

```
@Column(name = "id_file")
 long idFile;
```

Компилятор выдает ошибку, типо создается в бд такое же поле вторично.

Ниже приведена ентити бд, в которой есть вторичный ключ:

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "sticker")
    public class Sticker {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Column(name = "id")
        long id;
    //    @Column(name = "id_file")
    //    long idFile;
        @Column(name = "width")
        Double width;
        @Column(name = "height")
        Double height;
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "id_file")
        File file;
        public Sticker() {
        }
        public Sticker(long id,long idFile, Double width, Double height) {
            this.id=id;
           // this.idFile = idFile;
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }
    }
```

Ниже логи ошибки, если я сохраняю поле, которое закомментировано:

```
INFO: HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@5cde6747
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: jpaData] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at Main.main(Main.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: jpaData] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:967)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: ru.newtelegram.entity.Sticker column: id_file (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:835)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:875)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:607)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:889)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки покажите.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev добавил логи ошибки

Comment: Зачем вам отдельный мапинг для этого поля? Hibernate сам сгенерирует идентификтор для отношения.

Comment: И ещё один момент, `File` - это неудачно названная сущность или `java.io.File`?

Comment: неудачно названная сущность. уже переименовал. а как обратиться чтобы добавить данные ?у меня есть вариант самому create запрос писать через репозиторий

Answer (score 0):

Было бы лучше, если бы вы показали код и второй сущности. Но если в нём нет чего-нибудь особенного, то вам нужен примерно такой код:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Sticker {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    long id;

    @Column
    Double width;

    @Column
    Double height;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    File file;

    public Sticker() {
    }

    public Sticker(File file, Double width, Double height) {
        this.file = file;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}

File file = new File();
Sticker sticker = new Sticker(file, 100, 100);

session.persist(sticker);
```

Идентификторы СУБД сгенерирует сама.

Comment: то есть чтобы обратиться нужно в репозитории самостоятельно генерировать запрос для записи? или можно как то по-другому записать данные вторичного ключа

Comment: Приведённый код как раз записывает обе сущности в базу и автоматически устанавливает обеим идентификторы и значение внешнего ключа.